# How to check NSCache instance value set or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscache

I have an instance of `NSCache`, like: `NSCache *imageCache;` It is basically used for holding some remote "image" values with different `"@keys"`. I `alloc` & `init` `NSCache` in a Global class at the beginning and set a `if else` condition, like this:

```
if (self.imageCache == nil)
{
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"cache set");
}
```

I `#import` that "Global Class" in all of `ViewControllers`, so that I don't have to parse images every time. But the problem is when I go to other `ViewControllers` It seems like, `NSCache` `alloc` & `init` every time. Because It takes same time to load the images as `1stVC`. I think the `if else` condition didn't working perfectly or it's not the appropriate way to check either `NSCache` set or not.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it? One thing more, The `imageCache` is used from a global variable.
Thanks in advance.
Have a good day.

**ADDITION:**

This is the method where I load the `UIButtons` in `UIScrollView` as `subView`. This is a `UIViewClass` which I add in my "EveryViewController" as a `subView` Just take have a look on the `if (cachedImage)` line. It works fine. But when I want to check either the `NSCache` (iADImageCache) set or not, it shows me it's not set. But which should be set. In this situation how can I check all several `iADImageCache` with their different `@"Key"` name?
Thanks again.

```
-(void) loadUIButton
{
    [self loadScrollView];
    for (int i = 0; i < [iADDisplayArray count]; i++)
    {
        adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, ButtonWidth, ButtonHight)];

        currentAd = [iADDisplayArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *path = currentAd.bannerIconURL;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        UIImage *cachedImage =  [self.iADImageCache objectForKey:currentAd.bannerIconURL];
        if (cachedImage)
        {
            [adButtonOutLet setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //NSLog(@"OnecachedImage %@", cachedImage);
        }
        else
        {
            [self.iADImageCache setObject:originalImage forKey:currentAd.bannerIconURL];
            [adButtonOutLet setImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"OneimageCache %@", self.iADImageCache);
        }

        adButtonOutLet.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
        [adButtonOutLet setTag:i];
        [adButtonOutLet addTarget:self action:@selector(goToURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.iADScrollView addSubview:adButtonOutLet];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand why you should check if `iADImageCache ` is set or not. Even if it was null, means that you will try to call a method of a non instantiated object ( so, the `objectForKey:` method of `iADImageCache` ) and this will be a no-op (no operation) and will return null to the `cachedImage` object. Obviously, it's impossible that `iADImageCache` is not set but a `cachedImage` is returned properly from it. (PS: I suggest to move the `sendSynchronousRequest:` inside the else block, to avoid downloading the image even if you already have it cached).

Comment: @Luca laco, Yes, It makes me understand the thing. Moving `sendSynchronousRequest:` inside the `else` section, it seems like no more downloading image every time. :) Stay well dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a singleton class, instance at application did finish launching and use it wherever you are, through all the view controllers. In the singleton class put a property

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSCache* imageCache;
```

then instance it just once in the singleton class init method. In this way you don't have to care about it, and you can just add images to that cache. Of course you have to check if the image is cached or not based on the existance of a key inside that cache.

```
NSCache* globalCache = [SingletonClass sharedInstanceMethod].imageCache;
UIImage *imageX = [globalCache objectForKey: @"keyX"];
if (!imageX) {
    // download your image
    imageX = <Download method>;
    [globalCache setObject: imageX forKey: @"keyX"];
}

// Do your stuff (like showing the image)
....
...
..
.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: laco, Thanks for your comment. I'm going to add some code in my main post, so that you can understand the situation a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Unless actually needed across the whole program, I would suggest another approach that would restrict the caching to the class that actually needs to use it by adding the class method:

```
+ (NSCache *)staticCacheForClass
{
  static NSCache *staticCache;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    staticCache = [NSCache new];
    staticCache.name = @"myCache";
  });

  return staticCache;
}
```

Using this - you restrict the changes to the cache to be internal to the class that uses it and avoid creating another singleton. The cache is also preserved across creating and destroying instances of this class.

That said, a singleton could be a viable solution if you need to access the cache from different classes, since a cache singleton is not really a global state.

Cheers.